# Where can I see flutter windows logs?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a flutter app on windows with vscode. I don't see any logs when I run my app with `flutter run -d windows`, where am I supposed to see my logs?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the triangle and the circule and u find output and debug Console

Good luck (y)

[image: VS CODE LOG]